# Calling Java classes from IzPack

Tags: java, installation, izpack

How do you invoke a method from a Java class from IzPack? Static methods are OK, and I need to be able to pass it parameters.

Thank you!

---

Background info:

I am trying to write an IzPack installer which is able to detect a previously installed versions of the application. After finding out that it doesn't really support this feature (except in Windows), I think the only way to do this is through writing a Java class and calling it from IzPack.

Tim Williscroft has [previously suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845166/how-to-get-izpack-tocheck-for-an-existing-version-of-the-software) this method, that reads the value of a static field of a class:

```
 <condition type="java" id="jbossEnv">
             <java> 
                 <class>au.com.codarra.ela.installer.JBossChecker</class
                 <field>hasJBossEnv</field>
             </java>
             <returnvalue type="boolean">true</returnvalue>
 </condition>
```

However, is it possible to call `<java>` from somewhere other than a `<condition>` tag? I want to be able to call it from a `<variable>` tag.
Also, is it possible to call a method from a Java class instead of reading a value of a field? I want to be able to pass parameters to my class.

Answer (score 3):

You can call static methods, but I don't think you can pass in parameters. 
You *could* create a new 'Condition type', but I have no experience with this so I can't confirm the flexibility it provides...

*So, I don't have a direct response, but another suggestion which might help:*

I tend to pass any complex post-processing on to separate processes.

Have you investigated the Processing panel? *You can start any process, and pass in variables ..*

e.g.

```
<processing>
  <job name="do xyz">
    <os family="windows" />
    <executefile name="$INSTALL_PATH/scripts/xyz.bat">
      <arg>doit</arg><arg>$variable</arg>
    </executefile>
  </job>
  <job name="do xyz">
    <os family="unix" />
    <executefile name="$INSTALL_PATH/scripts/xyz.sh">
      <arg>doit</arg><arg>$variable</arg>
    </executefile>
  </job>
</processing>
```

I've used it to set up services and start up immediately. That kind of thing. Just make sure your script exits cleanly, otherwise IzPack will hang.

See here: 
http://izpack.org/documentation/panels.html#processpanel

Comment: +1 @amir : Aha I think that the processing panel is a new feature in IzPack, I don't think I've noticed it before... Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: Have another suggestion .. take a look at PackJacket. PackJacket wraps up IzPack with a GUI for building installers. Really nice tool: http://packjacket.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the IzPack Ant integration

http://izpack.org/documentation/advanced-features.html#apache-ant-integration

and the Ant Java callout task

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html

Comment: I am already using apache ant integration and the ant Java task... Do you have any suggestions specific to my question?

Comment: The thought is to wrap the callout into your Java class using Ant (although this is just repeating the suggestion above ...)

Answer (score 0):

Hello 
In the link below you will find a nice help about izpack installer.

http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=89

Link below contains a detailed pdf to make installer with izpack.

http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?attachment_id=112

cheers

Imran tariq

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully configured an IzPack installer that executes a "bat" file (with one parameter) during installation to generate a license request code. First I had to make sure that the bat file was copied to the user's chosen $INSTALL_PATH, and in the IzPack install.xml I added a ProcessPanel after the InstallPanel (which is where all the files, including the "bat" one, gets copied). My ProcessPanel.Spec.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<izpack:processing version="5.0"
xmlns:izpack="http://izpack.org/schema/processing" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://izpack.org/schema/processing 
http://izpack.org/schema/5.0/izpack-processing-5.0.xsd">

<job name="initialize license">
  <executefile name="$INSTALL_PATH/initialize.bat" workingDir="$INSTALL_PATH" onError="fail">
    <arg>license</arg>
  </executefile>
</job>
<onFail previous="false" next="false" />
<onSuccess previous="false" next="true" />
</izpack:processing>
```